# Wordpress, Conditional Statement, show form for a week per month

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress 4.2 site. And i have a mail form build with "Contact Form 7". I put it on a separate page with next statement:

```
[contact-form-7 id="2" title="Counter"]
```

I want to put it inside if else conditional statement to show it only a week per month. 
As I have read Wordpress has no a template server  language like Rails or Django.
How can I show some content only for a week per month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Shortcode:

You could create the `[visible]` shortcode and wrap it around your content:

```
[visible from="1" to="7"]
    [contact-form-7 id="2" title="Counter"]
[/visible]
```

where `from` and `to` are the *day of the month* values (1 - 31).

### Plugin:

Here's an untested demo plugin:

```
<?php 
/* Plugin Name: Visible - Shortcode */

add_shortcode( 'visible', function( $atts = [], $content = '' )
{
    $a = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'from' => '1',
            'to'   => '7',
        ], 
        $atts, 
        'visible_shortcode' 
    );

    $j = current_time( 'j' );

    return (int) $a['from'] <= $j && $j <= (int) $a['to']
        ? do_shortcode( $content ) 
        : __( 'Hidden!' );

} );
```

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.